# Is cookie provided by CookieAuthentication middleware secure?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-authentication

I'm using `app.UseCookieAuthentication` as follows(just a simple example);

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "MyAuthScheme",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
});
```

Then somewhere I'm manually creating `ClaimsPrincipal` and signing in user:

```
var claimCollection = new List<Claim>() 
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "First user"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "first@user.com")
};
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimCollection);
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

await context.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyAuthScheme", claimsPrincipal);
```

So generated cookie will contain information about user roles.

Now the question: is such generated cookie secure? I mean does ASP.NET encrypt it somehow so end user cannot manually modify it in a way so e.g. server would think that user is admin? 
Will server notice that cookie is corrupted when user modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Yes it's encrypted, so you can't see the contents.

Yes it's signed, so tampering will be detected.